# MeteorJS My friend request accept button is causing an uncaught RangeError, and I'm not using recursion

Tags: javascript, exception, meteor

My app has a friend request system, or at least that's what I'm trying to make right now. I have the request system all in place, now, but when I attempt to use the accept request button, it throws an uncaught rangeError exception. Everything I saw that was similar to my problem was using recursion.

Here's the relevant template html:

```
{{#each getRequests}}
        {{requester}} <button class='acceptFriend'>accept</button>
{{/each}}
```

Here's the relevant serverside JS:

```
acceptRequest: function(requesterId, requester){
        friends.update({owner:Meteor.userId()}, {$push:{ownerFriends:{friendId:requesterId, friendUsername:requester}}});
        friends.update({owner:requesterId}, {$push:{ownerFriends:{friendId:Meteor.userId(), friendUsername:Meteor.user.username}}});
        friendRequests.remove({requester:requester, target:Meteor.userId()});
    }
```

and here's the relevant client side JS:

```
acceptRequest: function(requesterId, requester){
        friends.update({owner:Meteor.userId()}, {$push:{ownerFriends:{friendId:requesterId, friendUsername:requester}}});
        friends.update({owner:requesterId}, {$push:{ownerFriends:{friendId:Meteor.userId(), friendUsername:Meteor.user.username}}});
        friendRequests.remove({requester:requester, target:Meteor.userId()});
    }
```

Edit: Here's the call stack

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceededEJSON.clone @
>   (program):528(anonymous function) @ (program):530_.each.*.forEach @
>
>   (program):164EJSON.clone @ (program):529(anonymous function) @
>
>   (program):530*.each.*.forEach @ (program):164EJSON.clone @
>
>   (program):529(anonymous function) @ (program):530*.each.*.forEach @
>
>   (program):164EJSON.clone @ (program):529(anonymous function) @
>
>   (program):530*.each._.forEach @ (program):164EJSON.clone @
>
> *(The same thing for a good while)*
>
> (program):529(anonymous function) @ (program):530_.each.*.forEach @
>
>   (program):164EJSON.clone @ (program):529(anonymous function) @
>
>   (program):530*.each._.forEach @ (program):164EJSON.clone @
>   (program):529(anonymous function) @ (program):530

Comment: Wait, by the call stack you just mean all of hte information from the exception, right? Or did you mean the order of the functions I called? Because the thing I editted is all the info I have on the error.

Comment: Oh damn, you can do that? Cool! Thanks for the help

Comment: Yeah that definitely sounds like it would be. How did you get it in the golden box, though, instead of in the obnoxious format I had it in?

Comment: With the quote marker `>`. You can see more in the markdown help.

Comment: Please note that I have deleted my previous comments as they were no longer relevant - The data has been edited in the question.

Comment: What is the `requester` helper?

Comment: The requester is the person who sent the request to the target person. It's the username of the user account. I'm using the default user accounts system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85349/discussion-between-subnatural-and-kyll).

Comment: `Meteor.user.username` should be `Meteor.user().username`

Comment: Oh, you're right. The issue is still happening, though.